# CSS styles rendering differently on windows 10 and ubuntu 20.04 LTS

Tags: html, css

I have been working on a basic chat app. I was working on ubuntu and I applied styles to each component according to the chrome browser on ubuntu. But on windows the styles are rendering differently, alignment is not proper and everything is bigger than expected.
Some of the solutions I tried so far (and still facing the same issue),

1. Using css reset - only `font-size` is reset
2. Using `line-height` instead of `padding` property - didn't work for me

Here are screenshots of the output on chrome browsers for windows 10 and ubuntu 20.04 LTS

**Chrome | Windows 10**
[image: Chrome | Windows 10]

**Chrome | Ubuntu 20.04 LTS**
[image: Chrome | Ubuntu 20.04 LTS]

May be there are simple ways to fix this problem.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

press ctrl and '-' to zoom out,
probably the website is just zoomed in, happens to me a lot.

Comment: Thanks @Post Malon for replying. Website zoom was the first thing I checked. The screenshots that I have attached are taken with 100% zoom for chrome browser. On windows 10 if I zoom out upto 75% then I get the desired display. But I want it on 100% zoom.

Answer (score 0):

**ISSUE**
I was facing the same issue. The websites which I made using tailwindcss in Ubuntu were around 10% zoomed out in my Windows 10.

**REASON**
Windows 10 by default zooms your all applications.

1. Right click on your windows 10 desktop.
2. Click Display Settings.
3. Therein display you can see the option Scale & Layout. And there by
   default the zoom is **125%**.
4. If you will change it to **100%** then you will see that your
   website is perfectly aligned same as Ubuntu.

**SOLUTION**
Maybe there could be some js fix for this out there but this will lead to more complexities.

Comment: OS-level zoom is necessary for high density monitors, unless you have a sharp eagle sight. If you're to bug your users with that, at least help them instead to tweak browser zoom for your specific page.